# Questions on differential forms and Cartan formalism

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

For the first time, I'm seriously trying to put to use differential forms and exterior algebra I learned long time ago in the context of GR calculations. I found two uses: 1. for the computation of connection coefficient functions $\Gamma^i_{jk}$ and Riemann tensor in the tetrad method, and 2. for integration theory on manifolds. I have somehow worked my way through relating the exterior derivative and the covariant derivative on 1-forms all by my own:
$$(d\omega)(X,Y)= X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X))-\omega([X,Y])$$
$$=\nabla_X(\omega(Y))-\nabla_Y(\omega(X))-\omega([X,Y])$$
$$=\nabla_X(\omega(Y))-\nabla_Y(\omega(X))-\omega([X,Y])$$
$$=(\nabla_X\omega)(Y)-(\nabla_Y\omega)(X)+\omega(\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX-[X,Y])$$
$$=(\nabla_X\omega)(Y)-(\nabla_Y\omega)(X)+\text{Tor}(\omega,X,Y)$$
From which the Cartan's first structural equation can be easily obtained by substituting the tetrad $e_i$ and its dual $\theta^i$ : $$\text{Tor}(\theta^i,\cdot,\cdot)=\Theta^i=d\theta^i+\omega^i_j\wedge\theta^j.$$ The problem is, nowhere in my calculation the metric is needed. So, I have no idea how it computes the Levi-Civita connection coefficients that are compatible with my metric. One might say that the choice of the tetrad gives us that, but even then the compatibility condition is never used. I am really confused here.

Other than that, I have some conceptual problems with the tetrads as well. Wouldn't the existence of tetrad mean that the manifold is parallelizable? Even a sphere can't have global non-zero basis. Do we only consider manifolds for which there is a global basis?

Regarding integration theory on manifolds, how are the integration measures constructed out of differential forms? Is there any good resource (textbooks, lecture notes etc.) on this? One that is sufficient for say, properly understanding Komar mass formula: $$M=\int_{\partial \Sigma}\star d(V_\flat)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartan’s two structural equations hold for any connection on the tangent bundle, not necessarily the Levi-Civita connection of a metric… this is a rather special case (though one of very huge interest). So, it’s not a problem in your calculation; that is to be expected. In the GR case, you impose the torsion to be zero, by hand, and then also impose metric-compatibility of the connection. See [Reading off connection 1-forms from Cartan's structural equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4398421/568204) on MSE for more about how to do the calculations with Cartan’s formalism to figure out the $\omega^i_{\,j}$ if that’s something you need. I recall MTW also has a section on this.

Next, of course, not every tangent bundle admits a global frame. These computations only make use of local frames. So, no contradiction anywhere.

Finally, regarding integration by manifolds, if you have a vector field $V$, you can (using the metric’s musical isomorphism) make it into a 1-form $V^{\flat}$, then by taking the exterior derivative, you get a 2-form $d(V^{\flat})$, and by taking the Hodge-dual you get an $(n-2)$-form, where $n=\dim M$ is the dimension of the manifold you’re working on. An $(n-2)$-form can then be integrated over an $(n-2)$-dimensional submanifold of $M$ (I assume $\Sigma$ is a dimension $(n-1)$ hypersurface, so $\partial\Sigma$ is an $(n-2)$-dimensional submanifold, so everything lines up nicely). The theory of integration of differential forms on manifolds can be found in any good textbook of advanced calculus/ differential geometry (Loomis-Sternberg, Spivak, Lee, or if you want to go more abstract/measure-theoretic route, see Amann-Escher Vol III, Lang, Dieudonne Vol III etc). I’ve personally written some answers on this topic, e.g [Why can integrals be written as $I=\int\phi(x)\epsilon$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/723234/203278), or [Integration on Hypersurfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4519553/568204). The Hodge-star stuff you’ll just have to learn algebraically somewhere (e.g. Loomis and Sternberg talk about it at the end of chapter 7). I’m sure this is also discussed in several physics texts, but I don’t particularly like the presentation with the swath of indices everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful answer. I will be checking the textbooks. And, for the formula I quoted, I understand that the form I am integrating and the dimension of the surface matches up. But I don't have much of a grasp on how to write down integral equations of geometric ideas. For example, here the idea is to follow Gauss's law in integral form in ED. I want to integrate the accleration (which in turn is (m/q) * E in ED) of a test particle over an enclosing 2-surface to find the charge (mass) enclosed. Here n=4 so n-2=2 as well. Why is the star needed then?

Comment: @RajatMondal because Maxwell’s equations are $dF=0$ (which encode $\nabla\cdot B=0$ and $\nabla\times E=-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$) and $d(\star F)=J$ (this encodes the other two equations $\nabla\cdot E=\rho$ and $\nabla\times B=J+\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$… where I set $\epsilon_0=\mu_0=1$ for simplicity), where $J$ is the current $(n-1)=3$-form. So, if you take a (oriented, 3-dimensional) hypersurface $\Sigma$ with boundary, then by Stokes’, $\int_{\Sigma}J=\int_{\Sigma}d\star F=\int_{\partial\Sigma}\star F=\int_{\partial\Sigma}\star dA$, where $A$ is the (4-co-)vector potential.

Comment: So, to capture the information about the charges and currents, you use (Stokes’ theorem and) the (inhomogeneous) Maxwell equation which talks about charges and currents, which turns out to be the one involving $\star F=\star dA$ (which really is what you expect since this is the one which encodes Gauss’ law for charges and Ampere’s law for currents). Note, I don’t specifically know much about the Komar mass, but based simply on the E&M analogy you brought up, this seems like a very direct connection.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it somewhat now.

Comment: I learned integration up to the point that I can evaluate them by pulling back from $R^n$ or using stokes theorem following Dieudonne (very repetitive). And my first question, considering $d<e_i,e_j>(X,Y)$, we will get extra equations that needs to be satisfied for metric compatibility of the connection 1 forms. I didn't know this because I'm trying to do this all by my own (confusing notations in popuar books) and have since derived identities(Ricci, Bianchi etc.) in this formalism and made connection to the tangent bundle picture. Your answer was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @RajatMondal I’m glad this was helpful, and yea at some point each person just has to do the calculations by themselves in their own notation (I couldn’t understand things any other way when I first started).